# one dropdown, 2 radios, 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, this could be hard to explain even in my native language but I will try to be as clear as possible.

I have one dropdown with different options. After choosing one of them, a user would need to check one of the two radio buttons which would finally give results in two different input fields.
For example - if you choose option 2 from dropdown, and then check radio button 1, then input one shows some value and input 2 shows some other value.

```
<select id="single">
    <option>Select an item</option>
    <option data1="140x200" data2="1">80x190</option>
    <option data1="140x200/220" data2="2">80x200</option>
    <option data1="140x220" data2="3">80x210</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" id="radioButton1" name="radioButton" value="enkel" />
<label for="radioButton1">enkel</label>
<input type="radio" id="radioButton2" name="radioButton" value="dubbel" />
<label for="radioButton2">dubbel</label>
<input type="text" id="dekbed">
<input type="text" id="overtrek">
```

I have this jsfiddle I made, so maybe it helps with clarification.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/astronaut/P7bJ5/39/)

Maybe i should give 4 attributes for each option in dropdown (data1, data2, data3, data4), so that for selected option it gives data1 to input #dekbed and data2 to input #overtrek if the radio1 is checked, and data3 to input #dekbed and data4 to input #overtrek if radio 2 is checked.

I hope you guys understood this, and I would really appreciate some help with this because I still haven't seen this way of selection before.

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is with your current code. What is it not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: It should give different results depending on which one of the radio buttons is checked. As it is now, it always gives the two options i pre-defined already. Let's say that I would like it to display the two results you can already see there, but only in case if radio 1 is checked, and two different results if radio 2 is checked.

Comment: astronaut: you want two more attributes to be added to each of the options in yoyr dropdown right? so that you can set the appropriate text in input text`s based on radio button as a second condition .

Comment: exactly! Conditions are like this: for selected option and radio button 1 checked, I want "data1" displayed in "dekbed" and "data2" displayed in "overtrek".
But for selected option and radio2 checked, there shold be something like "data3" displayed in "dekbed" and "data4" in "overtrek".

Comment: ok then why dont u add two more attributes with option tag  like data3 and data 4. later based on which radio button is checked, add appropriate value to respective input text field

Comment: i just added that, but the thing is that now i don't know how to write the script correctly, i tried though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a condition to check if each radio button is checked inside of the routine

```
 $("#single option:selected").each(function () {
```

For example for radioButton1 it would be

```
   if ($("#radioButton1").is(':checked')){  .... do something }
```

If radioButton1 is checked, change the values in dekbed and overtrek to data1 and data 2.

Otherwise if radioButton2 is checked

```
if ($("#radioButton2").is(':checked')){  .... do something different}
```

change the values in dekbed and overtrek to data3 and data 4.

Edit note: You will need to add these methods to both the change events of the select box, and the radio button inputs.

I created a fiddle demonstrating the solution at: [jsfiddle.net/dbS2Q/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/dbS2Q/1/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Here is how I wrote it following your instructions, and I obviously didn't write it correctly as it is not working (i am a newbie):
{
    $("#single option:selected").each(function () {
            $("#radiobutton1").is(':checked') 
            {('#dekbed').val($(this).attr('data1'));
            ('#overtrek').val($(this).attr('data2'));
            };
    });
    
};

{
    $("#single option:selected").each(function () {
        $("#radiobutton2").is(':checked') 
        {('#dekbed').val($(this).attr('data3'));
        ('#overtrek').val($(this).attr('data4'));
    };
    
        });
};

Comment: Not sure if i am allowed to link fiddle again, but i will try:
http://jsfiddle.net/astronaut/P7bJ5/42/

Comment: Hi, I updated the example, and I created a fiddle that I believe accomplishes what you're trying to do. Also, corrected the way I spelled radioButton1 and radioButton2 (case sensitive). You can view the updated fiddle at: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/9UQd2/1/

Comment: Thank you VERY much KP!! You are a lifesaviour :)
The only thing is that if I choose the size first and then check one of the buttons it turns no results, but it does if the radio is checked first and then choose the option from dropdown. Is there any solution to that?

Comment: Hi I updated the fiddle so that it also changes the values of the input boxes when the radio buttons are changed. I also updated the solution text to reflect the changes. The new fiddle is at: http://jsfiddle.net/dbS2Q/1/

Comment: This is it!! Thank you so very much!
Wish I had enough reputation points to rate your comment up, but I will be back when I have them to at least show my gratitude that way.